# Calling module's class method from skin/js file

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm inside a js file under `skin/frontend/base/default/js/` now to instantly update i need data from one of my custom modules controller class.

and i don't have idea on how to fetch data from the method.

as i go to url : `example.net/index.php/modulename/controller/method` i can see the data being populated. and this is what want to get in my js file.

Thank you !!

Comment: K.C.,create an ajax request at js file and send request to  this controller....

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer provided if it solved your problem. Alternately provide further feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an Ajax request within your js file, something along these lines:

```
pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];
admin_url = pathArray[4];
url = protocol + '//' + host + '/index.php/' + admin_url + '/controller/method';
new Ajax.Request('<your_url>', { //replace <your url> with the path to the action, i.e http://example.net/index.php/module
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
        var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
        alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
    },
    onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
});
```

http://prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax

This will point to the `methodAction()` method within your controller file, which will return the data you wish to fetch.

Comment: `function getBaseUrl() { return '<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>'; }` calling this doesn't give me base url, it returns me whole php code starting with `<?php` neither does echoing `$baseurl` as i'm in js file

Comment: Whoops, forgot we weren't within `.phtml`. I've updated the answer, give that a shot.